# How can I send resource to API through Content-Type: application/octet-stream php

Tags: php, curl, binary

I am trying to reproduce this POST https://www.screencast.com/t/OUE1StfLfyP7 in php but I couldn't archive that it works correctly because after downloading the image is not possible to open it

```
    $url = "https://internal-api-staging-lb.interact.io/v2/contacts/X/documents/fr_FR9.gif";

    $data = array('file' => '@'.realpath('https://www.viventura.de/images/icons/flags/fr_FR.gif'));

    // Initialize cURL
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/octet-stream", "authToken: XX"));
    // Set URL on which you want to post the Form and/or data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Data+Files to be posted
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    // Pass TRUE or 1 if you want to wait for and catch the response against the request made
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // For Debug mode; shows up any error encountered during the operation
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    // Execute the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I am doing something wrong someone can give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you try without CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER content-type ? did you try to get localy image https://www.viventura.de/images/icons/flags/fr_FR.gif and send if from your local ?

Comment: @fky yes is possible to get it locally, another idea? Thanks

Comment: did you try with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: @GustavoCatano did you find the solutions. I have stuck on the same issue